# Can't connect to mysql container from MySQL Workbench (Windows 10)

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, docker-toolbox

This is my 2 instances of docker images running.

```
$ docker ps

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                               NAMES
bb51b0b63b7d        mysql/mysql-server                "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mami_mysql
d7593fe55546        zarraozaga/dockerize-php-sample   "/usr/sbin/apache2ct…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                  apache_server
```

Hostname: **192.168.99.100**
Port: **3306**

Username and password are keyed in correctly.

This is the run command I executed

```
$ docker run --name mami_mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=mami -p 3306:3306 -d mysql/mysql-server
```

Im using windows 10 home edition and am currently running docker toolbox vm.

docker-machine ip
192.168.99.100

**Error:**

```
The error im receiving is Failed to connect to mysql at 192.168.88.199:3306 with user root. Host '192.168.99.1' is not allowed to connnect to mysql server. Username and password are all inputed correctly. Connection used, Standard TCP/IP
```

Comment: _Unfortunately im getting the error_ What error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to fix the issue.

I had to re-run it with this command.

> $ docker run -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -d mysql/mysql-server --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

After doing so i had to create a new user

> docker exec -ti a0498b91b646 mysql -uroot -p
>
> sql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'secret';

Then login to mysql with
username: monty
password: secret